# how to put the content of a <script> element in a function and run it?

Tags: javascript, function, console.log

i need to know how to get a script element's content in a function and re-execute it like that, or just rerun it without a function.

i tried it like this:

```
var something=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
function something2(){something.innerHTML}; 
something2();
```

it doesnt work.

i need this because on a website, a lot of console.log in the code breaks it if there is no console open. i cant edit the code since its not my website, but i can run javascript with userscripts.
so i did this:

```
var war=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[26];
war.innerHTML = war.innerHTML.replace(/console/g, "//console");
```

it works, but my script is ran way after the original code runs, or would run if it didnt break. so i need to rerun the content of the script element somehow.
also

```
eval(war.innerHTML);
```

gives a "Security Manager vetoed action" error.

Comment: In which browser is `console.log` still broken if there is no console?

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
var something=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
eval(something);
```